# Install Hue with standalone hbase on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, bigdata, hue

I have read all the previous asked questions and have searched this on google as well. But I was unable to find something working for me. I am new to Hbase so dont want to waste a lot of time on downloading different packages and at the end fails to get everything working.

I have installed Hbase0.98-hadoop2 on ubuntu and now want to install Hue as well. As I am newbie to this technology so wants to know how I can install hue on standalone ubuntu. I have not installed hadoop separately. All the tutorials I found on internet were with hadoop/oozie.

A detailed description on step by step installation would be very appreciative. You should also mention all pre requisite packages as well.

Regards

Comment: Can I know why my question has been down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just follow the steps mentioned in this question. Also, I was able to download the HUE but while installation, it prompted errors.

[Trying to install HUE but no success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143050/trying-to-install-hue-but-no-success)