# Trying to install HUE but no success

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bigdata, hue

I am trying to install hue on ubuntu and gets the following error when trying to install.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me why it's giving error for lber.h? I have installed all of the dependencies and using hue2.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your version of Ubuntu? Hue works well with the LTS 12:04 and [14:04](http://gethue.com/how-to-build-hue-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/).

Also make sure that you have installed the specific LDAP packages: https://github.com/cloudera/hue#development-prerequisites

Comment: Thanks @Romain  This helped me. Ubuntu version is 12